# Преимущества использования Django messages framework

Tags: django

1. В чем преимущества использования Django messages framework?
2. Зачем и как Django messages использует куки.
3. Почему нельзя просто захардкодить сообщение в шаблоне, например в случае успешной регистрации. Зачем нам django messages в этом случае.
   Есть ли пример, когда это будет лучшей практикой.
   Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Преимущество перед чем?
2. Django Messages использует сессию, чтобы хранить сообщения и передавать их пользователю. Если вы зашьете сообщение в код HTML, пользователь при каждом обновлении страницы увидит это сообщение снова. В большинстве случаев это неприемлемо. Есть много кейсов, когда сообщение через сессию являются лучшей практикой. Например, после отправки данных через форму на странице вы отображаете сообщение об успешном/не спешном сохранении данных в БД. Еще пример: вы хотите показать пользователю сообщение после logout, что такой-то пользователь вышел из системы.